# touchOverflowEnabled breaks a fixed div

Tags: jquery-mobile, css-position

On a jQuery Mobile project, I have a div which is on `position: fixed` and it works great.

But, when I activate the Touch Overflow with

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.touchOverflowEnabled = true;
});
```

The div is no longer fixed. Seems weird... Would you have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not solve your problem but TouchOverFlow I believe will be deprecated in 1.1 release:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/10/upcoming-releases-1-0-1-1-1-and-beyond/

> **Heads up**: `touchOverflow` to be deprecated in 1.1 – When we first introduced the `touchOverflow` feature, we saw it as a good way to
>   leverage the native overflow support in iOS to bring true fixed
>   toolbars and smoother transitions, even if it was for a fairly narrow
>   set of devices at the time. Now with the significant changes to fixed
>   headers and transition planned for 1.1, these will improve the
>   experience in an almost identical way as touchOverflow, except it will
>   work on a lot more platforms and with less complexity so we’ve decided
>   to retire this feature. It will be deprecated at 1.1 and removed at
>   1.2. We do have future plans for addressing overflow regions with internal scrolling so a lot of the work we’ve done on `touchOverflow`
>   will be re-purposed.

jQM 1.1 is scheduled to be release very soon

Comment: Oh, didn't saw this blog post. Hum, I guess I can put my menu issue on the side for a moment and wait for the 1.1. Thanks :)

Comment: I think jQM Team is expecting to release 1.1 ni the next week if not sooner